# Apply on companion object to aliased type

Tags: scala, companion-object

I want to make my Scala code more readable, so I added custom types for all parametrized types.

So I have in package object, for simplicity,

```
type IntSeq = Seq[Int]
```

However, now I cannot do simple `apply` on companion object. From REPL:

```
scala> IntSeq(1, 2, 3)
<console>:8: error: not found: value IntSeq
              IntSeq(1, 2, 3)
              ^
```

What to do?

*(just to make sure: my actual aliased objects are more complicated than `Seq[Int]`)*

edit: There is a similar question - [Scala type alias including companion object [beginner]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920573/scala-type-alias-including-companion-object-beginner-question?rq=1)

On that question, there are two replies, both of them not working.

One is to define my custom object with apply, but I am not sure how to do that in my case, plus it is a little verbose.

The other - to write `val IntSeq = Seq` produces the error

> warning: previously defined trait Seq is not a companion to value IntSeq.
>   Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.

Comment: Well, have you tried defining it using `:paste`?

Comment: I cannot find anything on what `:paste` means :( apparently, it's something to do with REPL, but I want it to work outside of REPL too, of course

Comment: Just type in the REPL and then copy-and-paste (or type) both the `type` alias and the `val` assignment after another. This is a REPL-only problem so it should not matter in other code.

Comment: Oh, OK, I get it, it was just an "issue" of REPL. OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second error is just because of the way REPL operates. In REPL, the companions must be defined together using the `:paste` mode; however, in the package object, that is not an issue.

So, the other approach - to write `val IntSeq = Seq` - will actually work.